# Typescript - Code fails to build from error TS1128: Declaration or Statement expected, but runs as expected when I serve the code

Tags: angular, npm

I am developing an Angular2 project, and I created a class that serves as my main Component class:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import { submitService } from './Common-functions/submit.service';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `htmlCode`

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{ 
  hideTable = true;
  lengthOfRecords = 0;
  lowerLimit = 0;
  upperLimit = 5;
  prevButtonDisabled = true;
  nextButtonDisabled = false;

  //User inputs

constructor(private sService:submitService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    public submitToJSON() {

         //SumbitJSON Object
            var submitJSON = {
                //inputData 
                     };

            this.sService.POST(submitJSON);
     }


   public returnDetails() {

    this.listOfIDs = {//ListData};

            this.hideTable = false;
        var keys = Object.keys(this.listOfIDs);
            var len = keys.length;
            this.lengthOfRecords = len;
        }

    public prev() {
            if(this.lowerLimit <= 0) {
                ;
                }
            else {
                this.lowerLimit = this.lowerLimit - 6;
                this.upperLimit = this.upperLimit - 5;
                this.nextButtonDisabled = false;
                if(this.lowerLimit <= 0) {
                    this.prevButtonDisabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
   public next() {
            if(this.upperLimit >= this.lengthOfRecords) {
                ;
                }
            else {
                this.lowerLimit = this.lowerLimit + 6;
                this.upperLimit = this.upperLimit + 5;
                this.prevButtonDisabled = false;
                if(this.upperLimit >= this.lengthOfRecords) {
                    this.nextButtonDisabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }

 getEntries(obj, from, to) {
        if(obj!=null) {
            var entries = [];
            for(var key in obj) {
                // extract index after `app`
                var index = key.substring(3);
                if(index >= from && index <= to) {
                    entries.push( obj[key]);
                }
            }
            return entries;
            }

 }

}
```

When I run npm start (which will run tsc -p ./), I get the following two errors:

```
app.appComponent.ts: error TS1128:Declaration or statement expected
app.appComponent.ts: error TS1128:Declaration or statement expected
```

At the following lines of code

```
---> public submitToJSON() {

     //SumbitJSON Object
        var submitJSON = {
            //inputData };

        this.sService.POST(submitJSON);
 }
```

And at the last line of the code.  I have been modifying the code the whole day, and only removing the OnInit related code fixes it.  What am I doing wrong?  I'm new to Angular2, so any information would be helpful.  I am also running tsc version 3.1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have commented

```
//inputData };
```

I think the curly brace should be on the next line...

```
//inputData
};
```

**Edit**

Your ngOnInit function should not contain other functions:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import { submitService } from './Common-functions/submit.service';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `htmlCode`

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{ 
  hideTable = true;
  lengthOfRecords = 0;
  lowerLimit = 0;
  upperLimit = 5;
  prevButtonDisabled = true;
  nextButtonDisabled = false;

  //User inputs

constructor(private sService:submitService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    // Add any initialization code here
}

submitToJSON() {

     //SumbitJSON Object
        var submitJSON = {
            //inputData 
                 };

        this.sService.POST(submitJSON);
 }


returnDetails() {

this.listOfIDs = {//ListData};

        this.hideTable = false;
    var keys = Object.keys(this.listOfIDs);
        var len = keys.length;
        this.lengthOfRecords = len;
    }

prev() {
        if(this.lowerLimit <= 0) {
            ;
            }
        else {
            this.lowerLimit = this.lowerLimit - 6;
            this.upperLimit = this.upperLimit - 5;
            this.nextButtonDisabled = false;
            if(this.lowerLimit <= 0) {
                this.prevButtonDisabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
next() {
        if(this.upperLimit >= this.lengthOfRecords) {
            ;
            }
        else {
            this.lowerLimit = this.lowerLimit + 6;
            this.upperLimit = this.upperLimit + 5;
            this.prevButtonDisabled = false;
            if(this.upperLimit >= this.lengthOfRecords) {
                this.nextButtonDisabled = true;
                }
            }
        }

 getEntries(obj, from, to) {
    if(obj!=null) {
        var entries = [];
        for(var key in obj) {
            // extract index after `app`
            var index = key.substring(3);
            if(index >= from && index <= to) {
                entries.push( obj[key]);
            }
        }
        return entries;
        }



}
```

Comment: Hi!  Sorry, I did that when I posted to StackOverflow, just to not be too verbose.  The code has the curly bracket on the next line.  I'll fix it

Comment: The ngOnInit function should not contain other functions. I have updated my response to include what I believe your ngOnInit should be.

Comment: Thanks, that did help!  I guess I didn't fully understand the OnInit tutorial.  However, when I try to build the code now, I get the message "error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target".  Does this mean I am not creating my object of class submitService correctly?

Comment: Actually, I figured that one out, and it was a silly mistake!  I'll mark this as the answer, as it fixed my issue :)

Answer (score 46):

In my case was just necessary to compile again the project

Comment: My WebStorm also was fixed after reopening. Thanks

Comment: My fix was to restart the Typescript Service in Webstorm.

Answer (score 34):

Just had the same error and it went away after closing IntelliJ and reopening.  I had been modifying the file with the error.  It is like it was looking at an old version somehow.

Comment: Same thing on Webstorm (also a Jetbrains product). Didn't expect a restart would do the trick, but it did! Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, restart solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio code I had to kill npm start
and then run again

```
npm run start
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who experiencing problems with linter: It often happens with me in WebStorm that some linter error sits there forever. Restarting IDE works as Marshall Thompson suggested, but closing file tab and opening it solves the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no syntax error and you still see it, try restarting the IDE. (For me the issue was fixed after reopening Webstorm IDE)